# Customised Data Detection with UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

How can I detect custom data pattern in UITextView, for an example say I have this text in the  UITextView

```
textView.text = @"Finally you guys won !! @Chock @Sanda #winners #amazing";
```

I want to get notified when a user tap on word starting with @ or #. Thank You

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/rootd/AMAttributedHighlightLabel

Answer (score 1):

I hope this library will solve your problem :

**Reference:** https://github.com/rootd/AMAttributedHighlightLabel

```
AMAttributedHighlightLabel *tweetLabel = [[AMAttributedHighlightLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..,..,..,..)];
tweetLabel.delegate = self;
tweetLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
tweetLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
tweetLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
[tweetLabel setString:@"This #is a @test for my #@new http://AMAttributedHighlightLabel.class"];

tweetLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
tweetLabel.mentionTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
tweetLabel.hashtagTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
tweetLabel.linkTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:129.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:193.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
tweetLabel.selectedMentionTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
tweetLabel.selectedHashtagTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
tweetLabel.selectedLinkTextColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x4099FF);

NSError *error;
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"((@|#)([A-Z0-9a-z(é|ë|ê|è|à|â|ä|á|ù|ü|û|ú|ì|ï|î|í)_]+))|(http(s)?://([A-Z0-9a-z._-]*(/)?)*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

tweetLabel.regex = regex;

[self.view addSubview:tweetLabel];
```